# Getting last similar item out of Map in Java

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have a Map that has been alphabetically sorted by converting it using TreeMap.
The Map contains both a String (installer file name) and Path (installer path on file system) for instance
Map installers;

I need to obtain the most recent installer file name. However, regex seems like it'd be too complicated.

The code I have currently to display the installers and their paths is this:

```
 Map<String, Path> installers = findInstallers();
    Set s = installers.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String installerFile = (String) entry.getKey();
        Path installerPath = (Path) entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(installerFile + " ==> " + installerPath.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("================================");

private Map<String, Path> findInstallers() {

    HashMap<String, Path>  installerPathMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        Path productReleasePath = Paths.get("C:", "test");
        List<Path> allPaths = Files.walk(productReleasePath)
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        allPaths.forEach(path -> {
            if (!path.toFile().getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".log")) {
                String installerFiileName = path.toFile().getName();
                installerPathMap.put(installerFiileName, path);
             }
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new TreeMap<>(installerPathMap);
}
```

This is a sample output:

```
Client_1.exe ==> C:\test\build_1\Win32\Client_1.exe
Client_5.exe ==> C:\test\build_5\Win32\Client_5.exe
Client_6.exe ==> C:\test\build_6\Win32\Client_6.exe
Server_1.exe ==> C:\test\build_1\Win64\Server_1.exe
Server_2.exe ==> C:\test\build_2\Win64\Server_2.exe
Server_Linux_1.tar.gz ==> C:\test\build_1\Linux32\Server_Linux_1.tar.gz
Server_Linux_2.tar.gz ==> C:\test\build_2\Linux32\Server_Linux_1.tar.gz
================================
```

I need to shorten my Map to only contain the highest key and it's value pair, so the output is similar to this:

```
Client_6.exe ==> C:\test\build_6\Win32\Client_6.exe
Server_2.exe ==> C:\test\build_2\Win64\Server_2.exe
Server_Linux_2.tar.gz ==> C:\test\build_2\Linux32\Server_Linux_1.tar.gz
================================
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the paths to a map using the root of the installer name as a key (i.e. the part before the underscore), and discard the lowest version when there is a key collision, you'll get what you want.

Note that sorting the names alphabetically won't work because version 9 will sort after 10, so you'll have to extract the version and do a numeric comparison.

I'm not certain of your naming convention, but the helper functions in the following example should be easy enough to modify if my assumptions aren't correct.

```
public class InstallerList {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path productReleasePath = Paths.get("C:", "test");

        Collection<Path> installers = Files.walk(productReleasePath)
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .filter(p -> !p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".log"))
            // Collect files with the highest version
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // Key is installer name *without* version
                InstallerList::extractName,
                // Value mapper; identity mapping to the path
                p -> p,
                // Select newest version when there is a collision
                InstallerList::newer
            ))
            .values();

        for (Path path : installers) {
            System.out.println(path.getFileName() + " ==> " + path);
        }
    }

    // Extract the root name of an installer from a path (up to but not including the last '_')
    public static String extractName(Path path) {
        String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('_');
        if (i < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName);
        }
        return fileName.substring(0, i);
    }

    // Return the path with the highest version number
    public static Path newer(Path p1, Path p2) {
        return extractVersion(p1) > extractVersion(p2) ? p1 : p2;
    }

    // Extract a version number from a path (number between the last '_' and the following '.')
    private static int extractVersion(Path path) {
        String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
        int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('_');
        if (i < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName);
        }
        int j = fileName.indexOf('.', i);
        if (j < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(fileName);
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(fileName.substring(i + 1, j));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no standard naming convention for the installer file names. Some have dashes in the name, others have underscores, but this should be a good starting point.  Other's have the full version number vs just build number. 

 For example: 
    `code` WebAgent-1.2.3.zip

Thanks for the help!